# Any information on how to call external web services from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: web-services, google-cloud-platform

Want to invoke external services in case of any event occurred in GCP pub/sub component like if there is any message received in GCP pub/sub api then it should invoke external service outside GCP with those message details. Any information on how to call external web services from Google Cloud Platform would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

For your specific scenario, I suggest the following approach:

1. Understand [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) and specifically configure a Pub/Sub Trigger, such that if a message is published to a Pub/Sub topic, then your Google Cloud Function is triggered i.e. executed. Here is [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub) to how you can use Pub/Sub and Google Cloud Functions together.
2. Now, look at your Cloud Function code above and in that, you can then write the code for any external API that you wish to integrate. E.g. invoke any external and reachable REST Endpoint or any client library code (e.g. External Email Sending solutions like SendGrid or Mailjet).

Comment: Information is useful, thank you

Comment: I am trying to deploy function that should be invoked when there is new message received in topic, i am trying to deploy sample function from "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples". I have created zip file which contains folder structure -> pom.xml and src/sub-folders as mentioned in GCP documentation, i am deploying using 'ZIP upload' option. But i am getting error as "Build failed: function has neither pom.xml nor already-built jar file; directory has these entries: .googlebuild, hello-pubsub; Error ID: 9de11b0d". Any idea what went wrong?